# New line character in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How can I take the new line characters in the middle of words... below words in Notepad++ (which is on different lines)

[image]

where i should remove the new line character from the address value of cust_id- 102140

result should be

[image]

Comment: This could be tricky since Notepad++ does not appear to support multiple line regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Notepad++ works fine with regular expressions searching multiple lines, just use a mix of `\n` and `\r` in both the search and the replace fields (or the more general `\R` in the search field). Notepad++ before version 6 was weak. Version 6 introduced proper regular expressions and it is now on version 7.4.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I attempted an answer below but I don't know if it works because I don't have access to Notepad++ at the moment.

Comment: You can paste your text and mark it as code to let users to recreate your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regex find and replace:

**Find:**

```
(^\d{6} .*?)\r?\n(?!\d{6})(.*?\r?\n)
```

**Replace:**

```
$1 $2
```

Of note, the negative lookahead `(?!\d{6})` makes sure that the following line does not begin with six digits.  This ensures that we only combine lines which represent a spillover.

Comment: Tim, appears to work on my Notepad++ (v7.3.3). The replacement should probably be `$1 $2` to replace the line break with a space. If there is already a space there it may be neater to discard it and insert one explicit space. Can do thisby changing the middle of the search term to be `\h*\r?\n\h*` (where `\h` matches horizontal while space).

Comment: @AdrianHHH I _think_ my pattern should already be capturing horizontal space, so I will just go with your first suggestion.